# Data is not recognised inside setTimeout inside another closure

Tags: javascript, initialization, vuejs2, settimeout, jquery-form-validator

I have my data, and I am trying to access it within an initializer inside setTimeout.

```
 data() {
    return { val: {} }
 },

 methods: {
    test() { 
         console.log(this.val) // works 

         var self = this

         setTimeout(function() {
              console.log(this.val) // works                 
              var check = this.myMethod()

              $.validate({
                   onError: function($form) {
                        console.log(self.val) // doesn't work       
                   }
              })

         }, 500)
    },

    myMethod() {
       // some stuff
       return true
    }
 }
```

This is the updated code. Using the `var self = this` approach, I am now gettign:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function

Comment: this changed in setTimeout callbacks. you need to use some self trick;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data() {
    return { val: {} }
 },

 methods: {
    test() { 
         console.log(this.val) // works
         var self = this;
         setTimeout(function() {
              console.log(self.val) // works                 

              $.validate({
                   onError: function($form) {
                        console.log(self.val) // doesn't work       
                   }
              })

         }, 500)
    }
 }
```

Try this. You often lose the value of this when calling functions within functions, so we store this in a variable to make it accessible from nested functions.

Comment: Trying this throws me `this.myMethod is not a function` - `myMethod()` is another method in my methods object. :/

Comment: @senty everywhere that you use `this` inside the `setTimeout` callback you will need to use `self`.

Comment: @senty Don't combine `bind` and `self`. If you are using the method described in this answer, just use `self` and remove `bind`. So if you have a `this.myMethod` somewhere, change it to `self.myMethod`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't use `self.val`. Now I used `self.val` and removed `.bind()`, also set `var self = this`. It is returning me : `Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function` - `myMethod` is just another method in `methods` object. On first line inside setTimeout, I use `var check = this.myMethod()`, maybe that is causing the issue

Comment: @senty try change var check = this.myMethod() to var check = self.myMethod()

Answer (score -2):

```
 methods: {
    test() { 
        console.log(this.val) // works
        // for this -> self trick
        let self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
              console.log(self.val) // works                 

              $.validate({
                   onError: function($form) {
                        console.log(self.val) // doesn't work       
                   }
              })

         }, 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of the bind function is so you can avoid the `let self = this;` antipattern. Don't mix them.

Comment: This is still returning undefined. You set the self but didn't give it into the setTimeout. Trying this also gives me undefined

Comment: There's a feature named closure in ES2015, which make the timeout callback can access outer function's variables.

Comment: Can you give me an explanation what's the down voting for?

Comment: Have you tested if the console.log(self.val) in the onError outputs anything or not?

Comment: As it stands you are combining `bind` (the last line of actual code in the answer) with a closure. Also, `let self = this` needs to be *inside* the `test` method.

Comment: I think it's okay for putting self = this in methods directly. As for binding, you are right. corrected accordingly.

Comment: You made it exactly the same with the accepted answer

Comment: Yes, but my answer came earlier, so I should keep it and revise it until it works.

Comment: I updated your answer to fix what I was talking about above. Note the change. FWIW, I'm not one of the downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I believe it's not you.